# Rounding int to 1 decimal place?

Tags: java

So in the following set of code I don't understand why "%.1f" will not round y to 1 decimal, I get the following when running the program:

```
123 F = Exception in thread "main" 
    java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2761)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2708)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
    at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
    at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
    at Check03A.main(Check03A.java:17)
```

I also tried Math.round(y * 10) / 10 but it gives me for example 29.0 instead of 28.9

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import type.lib.*;

public class Check03A

{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        print.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        int y = 5 * (x - 32) / 9;
        print.printf(x + " F = " + "%.1f", y + " C");
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing integer division, which rounds down.  You need to have a float somewhere.  For instance: `float y = 5 * (x - 32) / 9f;`

Comment: if you use `int` datatype to store decimal value. it neglects the decimal part.

Comment: @Jared this is one problem, yes, but unrelated to the main problem (the exception)

Comment: @fge it will get resolved when you change the datatype of `y` to `float`

Comment: @nitish005 nope; even if `y` is a `float`, `y + "C"` will be a `String`

Comment: @fge I think the main problem is the fact that `y` is never a decimal value.  Yes, there is the incorrect semantics of the `printf` method, but that seems minor compared to the problem with `y` being an `int`.  It seems clear that the OP is mixing the `print/ln` methods with the `printf` method.

Comment: @Jared not that minor; OP seems to have a problem understanding how `.printf()` works at all. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @fge: you are right. sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
print.printf(x + " F = " + "%.1f", y + " C");
```

There are two arguments to this method:

- `x + " F = " + "%.1f"` (the format string),
- `y + "C"` (the argument)

Condensing the first argument, the statement becomes:

```
print.printf(x + "F = %.1f", y + "C");
```

The problem: `y + "C"`. Why? Well, one argument of the `+` operator is a `String`; therefore, this `+` becomes a string concatenation operator and what the argument will ultimately be is `String.valueOf(y) + "C"`.

But the format specification in the format string is`%.1f`, which expects a `float` or `double`, or their boxed equivalents. It does not know how to handle a `String` argument.

Hence the error.

---

There is also the problem that you are doing an integer division, but this is not the topic of this question. Provided that all numeric problems are solved, your printing statement will ultimately be:

```
print.printf("%.1f F = %.1f C", x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintStream print = new PrintStream(System.out);
        print.println("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        //change it
        float y = 5 * (x - 32) / 9;
        print.printf(x + " F = " + "%.1f", y).print(" C");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `y` as float if you want to use `%f`

```
float y = 5 * (x - 32) / 9;
print.printf(x + " F = " + "%.1f", y ).print("C");
```

Comment: `y` would still be an integer value (assuming that that value could be exactly represented as a float) unless you also make `x` a float.